# React 0.13 get data from REST endpoint

Tags: reactjs

Working with older React.

How to correctly get data from an endpoint?

It complains about state

I am a React newbie. Looked on Tutorials but it seems developer who did this code used some other convention in creating Classes/Components.

Tried this:

```
import React from "react"
import Utils from "utils"
import {A, makeUrl, redirectTo} from "routing"
import Settings from "settings"
import ProjectApi from "api/project"
import FlashMessagesService from "flash_messages"

var ProjectHeader = React.createClass({

    displayName: 'ProjectHeader',

    state = {
      project: [],
    },

    componentDidMount() {

        // need to make the initial call to getData() to populate
        // data right away

        // Now we need to make it run at a specified interval
        setInterval(this.refresh, 1000); // runs every 5 seconds.
      },


refresh : function(){
     var props = this.props
       var providers = Settings.providers['project.header.info'] || []

    providers
          .filter(function(provider) {
            return provider.component.isApplicable(props.project)
          })
          .forEach(function (provider) {
            projectInfo.push(<provider.component project={props.project} {...props}/>)
          })


    fetch('/api/v1/project/'+props.project.pk)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.setState({ project: data.project });
          });

    if (this.state.project.analysis_status == 'succeeded') {

    window.location.reload();

    }

    },
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo in the state line (line 11) which should have been `state: {` rather than `state = {`. Another potential complaint it might have had is that during runtime after the component was unmounted, the interval would've continued firing, so I added a `clearInterval` in `componentWillUnmount`.

```
import Utils from 'utils';
import { A, makeUrl, redirectTo } from 'routing';
import Settings from 'settings';
import ProjectApi from 'api/project';
import FlashMessagesService from 'flash_messages';

var ProjectHeader = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'ProjectHeader',
  intervalId: null,
  state: {
    project: [],
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    // need to make the initial call to getData() to populate
    // data right away

    // Now we need to make it run at a specified interval
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.refresh, 1000); // runs every 5 seconds.
  },
  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  },

  refresh: function () {
    var props = this.props;
    var providers = Settings.providers['project.header.info'] || [];

    providers
      .filter(function (provider) {
        return provider.component.isApplicable(props.project);
      })
      .forEach(function (provider) {
        projectInfo.push(
          <provider.component project={props.project} {...props} />
        );
      });

    fetch('/api/v1/project/' + props.project.pk)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ project: data.project });
      });
    console.log(hits);
    if (hits.analysis_status == 'succeeded') {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks. Had to use this.state.project to later reference it

Comment: Maybe you can help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61055704/react-how-to-update-dom-component-after-render-function Same code, different problem