# React how to update DOM component after render function

Tags: reactjs

New to React. Using React 0.13

Anybody can give me a link or hint how to update the component after render.

Was looking through docs and trying different things, but was not able to achieve it.

I want to change reanalyzeButton to this in a refresh:

"reanalyzeButton =  Check for new commits"

How can I reference it/update it???

```
refresh : function(){

<here I want to update DOM component - change text of reanalyzeButton>

}



render : function(){

<code>
.
.
.


        var reanalyzeButton
        var queuePosition

        queuePosition = <span>You&#39;re at position {props.project.analysis_queue_position}</span>

        if (props.project.analysis_status == 'in_progress') {
            reanalyzeButton = <A onClick={this.analyzeProject} title="Request a re-analysis of the project"><i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" /> Analysis in progress</A>
        } else if ((!props.project.analyze) || props.project.analysis_priority == 0) {
            reanalyzeButton = <A onClick={this.analyzeProject} title="Request an analysis of the project"><i className="octicon octicon-sync"/> Check for new commits</A>
        } else {
            reanalyzeButton = <span><i className="octicon octicon-sync" /> Project queued for analysis: <strong>{queuePosition}</strong>.</span>
        }
.
.
.

return  <div className="project-header" itemScope itemType="http://schema.org/Code">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                            <div className="clearfix">
                                {projectHeader}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                            <span className="badge">
                                <A href={["admin","owner"].some(role => props.project.user_role == role) ? makeUrl('/project/'+props.project.pk+'/settings',{tab : 'badges'}) : makeUrl('/project/'+props.project.pk)}><img src={"/api/v1/project/"+props.project.pk+"/badge.svg"} /></A>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            <ul className="meta">
                                {fetchStatus}{projectInfo} <li>{reanalyzeButton}</li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul className="tags hidden-xs">
                                {tagList}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row clearfix hidden-xs">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            {projectDescription}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {props.tabs}
                </div>
    },
```

**Update 1:**

Error:

TypeError: this.state is null

Modified the code like this? But it does not work ....

```
var ProjectHeader = React.createClass({

    displayName: 'ProjectHeader',
    intervalId: null,
    state: {
    projectjson: [],
    label: '',
  },

    componentDidMount() {


        // Now we need to make it run at a specified interval
        this.intervalId = setInterval(this.refresh, 1000);
        this.setState({ label: '<span><i className="octicon octicon-sync" /> Project queued for analysis: <strong>{queuePosition}</strong>.</span>'});
      },

refresh : function(){

   if (this.state.projectjson.analysis_status == 'succeeded') {
     // window.location.reload();
      //this.render2()
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
     this.setState({label: '<A onClick={this.analyzeProject} title="Request an analysis of the project"><i className="octicon octicon-sync"/> Check for new commits</A>'});
    }

render : function(){

  if (props.project.analysis_status == 'in_progress') {
            //reanalyzeButton = <A onClick={this.analyzeProject} title="Request a re-analysis of the project"><i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" /> Analysis in progress</A>
            reanalyzeButton = this.state.label
        } else if ((!props.project.analyze) || props.project.analysis_priority == 0) {
            //reanalyzeButton = <A onClick={this.analyzeProject} title="Request an analysis of the project"><i className="octicon octicon-sync"/> Check for new commits</A>
           reanalyzeButton = this.state.label
        } else {
            //reanalyzeButton = <span><i className="octicon octicon-sync" /> Project queued for analysis: <strong>{queuePosition}</strong>.</span>
            reanalyzeButton = this.state.label
        }
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest you to use jsx component, rather than putting your code in html. Then, the problem is that in the function that you're passing in the onClick you should update the state with `setState()`. When you properly update the state, React automatically render again the elements related to the state change

Comment: Thanks. Update the code to code similar to Update 1: but it gets an error. Can you help here?

Comment: Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059383/state-is-null-in-react?noredirect=1#comment108021955_61059383